# Есть способ принудить html-редакторы использовать `<br>` вместо `<p>`?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Набиваю текст справки в HTML. Онлайновые HTML-редакторы при создании новой строки в визуальном редакторе, создают её через тег `<p>`, но мне не нужен новый параграф. Но это не правильно и замусоривает HTML-документ.

Есть ли методы принуждения таких редакторов к использованию `<br>` тега? А то бессмыслица какая-то получается с этими тегами `<p>`, потом разгребай эту кашу.

Comment: Вы о чем?  Ничего не понял...

Comment: В html-редакторе жмёшь Enter, новая строка оформляется при помощи `<p>`, а нужно `<br>`.

Comment: Во-первых, Капитан Очевидность замечает, что это всё зависит от конкретного html-редактора. Во-вторых, может редактор умеет Shift+Enter?

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо. Пробовал разные редакторы, но до shift+enter не додумался. Именно так они и делают тег `<br>`.

Comment: скинь ссылку, просто стало инетресно

Comment: html-online.com/editor/